# blogspot pagination: how to remove older posts text and replace it with the line numbers when accessing labels?

Tags: blogger

When I access a blogspot label, the page always show older posts text. If I use `max-result` it show the line numbers but I feel it's not a SEO friendly url with `max-result` suffix, the phrase `/search/label` is bad enough for SEO.

I want to know how to remove older posts text and replace it with the line numbers when accessing labels.  Like this

[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem!

Thanks very much!

Here is the code

```
var perPage = 12;
 var numPages=5;
 var firstText ='Trang đầu';
 var lastText ='Trang cuối';
 var prevText ='Trang trước';
 var nextText ='Trang kế';
 var urlactivepage=location.href;
 var home_page="/";

if (typeof firstText == "undefined") firstText = "First";
if (typeof lastText == "undefined") lastText = "Last";
var noPage;
var currentPage;
var currentPageNo;
var postLabel;
pagecurrentg();

function looppagecurrentg(pageInfo) {
    var html = '';
    pageNumber = parseInt(numPages / 2);
    if (pageNumber == numPages - pageNumber) {
        numPages = pageNumber * 2 + 1
    }
    pageStart = currentPageNo - pageNumber;
    if (pageStart < 1) pageStart = 1;
    lastPageNo = parseInt(pageInfo / perPage) + 1;
    if (lastPageNo - 1 == pageInfo / perPage) lastPageNo = lastPageNo - 1;
    pageEnd = pageStart + numPages - 1;
    if (pageEnd > lastPageNo) pageEnd = lastPageNo;
    html += "<span class='showpageOf'>Page " + currentPageNo + ' of ' + lastPageNo + "</span>";
    var prevNumber = parseInt(currentPageNo) - 1;
    if (currentPageNo > 1) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="showpage firstpage"><a href="' + home_page + '">' + firstText + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum firstpage"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">' + firstText + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    if (currentPageNo > 2) {
        if (currentPageNo == 3) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="showpage"><a href="' + home_page + '">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            }
        } else {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + prevNumber + ');return false">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + prevNumber + ');return false">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            }
        }
    }
    if (pageStart > 1) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="' + home_page + '">1</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">1</a></span>'
        }
    }
    if (pageStart > 2) {
        html += ' ... '
    }
    for (var jj = pageStart; jj <= pageEnd; jj++) {
        if (currentPageNo == jj) {
            html += '<span class="pagecurrent">' + jj + '</span>'
        } else if (jj == 1) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="' + home_page + '">1</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">1</a></span>'
            }
        } else {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + jj + ');return false">' + jj + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + jj + ');return false">' + jj + '</a></span>'
            }
        }
    }
    if (pageEnd < lastPageNo - 1) {
        html += '...'
    }
    if (pageEnd < lastPageNo) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastPageNo + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastPageNo + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    var nextnumber = parseInt(currentPageNo) + 1;
    if (currentPageNo < (lastPageNo - 1)) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + nextnumber + ');return false">' + nextText + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + nextnumber + ');return false">' + nextText + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    if (currentPageNo < lastPageNo) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum lastpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastText + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum lastpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastText + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    var pageArea = document.getElementsByName("pageArea");
    var blogPager = document.getElementById("blog-pager");
    for (var p = 0; p < pageArea.length; p++) {
        pageArea[p].innerHTML = html
    }
    if (pageArea && pageArea.length > 0) {
        html = ''
    }
    if (blogPager) {
        blogPager.innerHTML = html
    }
}

function totalcountdata(root) {
    var feed = root.feed;
    var totaldata = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t, 10);
    looppagecurrentg(totaldata)
}

function pagecurrentg() {
    var thisUrl = urlactivepage;
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
        } else {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?&max"))
        }
    }
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
            currentPage = "page";
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
        } else {
            currentPage = "label";
            if (thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=") == -1) {
                perPage = 20
            }
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1" ><\/script>')
        }
    }
}

function redirectpage(numberpage) {
    jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
    noPage = numberpage;
    var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
    newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
    newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
    nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}

function redirectlabel(numberpage) {
    jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
    noPage = numberpage;
    var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
    newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
    newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary/-/" + postLabel + "?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
    nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}

function finddatepost(root) {
    post = root.feed.entry[0];
    var timestamp1 = post.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + post.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
    var timestamp = encodeURIComponent(timestamp1);
    if (currentPage == "page") {
        var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    } else {
        var pAddress = "/search/label/" + postLabel + "?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    }
    location.href = pAddress
}
```

Comment: could you atach the pagination script or a live example of it

Comment: Hey @Bouh I updated the code, can you take look for me?

Comment: If I delete the "Older Post" text link, the pagination disappear too. You can see it work live [here](https://www.nhadatsonnghia.com/search/label/mua-ban-nha-dat-go-vap)

Comment: Hey @Bouh, can you help me looking for this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/q/58987013/12088833](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58987013/12088833)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the script from:

```js
// old version
if(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
  if(thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
    postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
  } else {
    postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?&max"))
  }
}
```

To:

```js
if(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
  if(thisUrl.indexOf(/\?[a-z-]+=/g) != -1) {
    postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf(/\?[a-z-]+=/g))
  } else {
    postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.match(/\?|#|&|$/).index)
  }
}
```

Check the full version of your code from [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/c2F9KBA8)

Comment: It works bro :D . You're the best ! thanks so much. Have a nice day bro!